# difference between `focusable` and `clickable`

Tags: android, focus, clickable

What is the difference between `clickable` and `focusable` in android?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`Clickable` means that it can be clicked by a pointer device or be tapped by a touch device. `Focusable` means that it can gain the focus from an input device like a keyboard. Input devices like keyboards cannot decide which view to send its input events to based on the inputs itself, so they send them to the view that has *focus*.

Answer (score 12):

`Focusable` means ACTION_UP event will occur. It will gain it and it won't release it.

`Clickable` means ACTION_DOWN first and ACTION_UP at the end. It will gain and release it at the end.

Comment: Shouldn't `Clickable` be first ACTION_DOWN and then ACTION_UP?